# Browser console repeatedly prints "Error calling method on NPObject" on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, advertising, javascript

I was not signed into the site when I got this error.

When I open any question on the Stack Overflow site, if I open the browser console, I keep getting an error message being continuously printed.

On Chrome, this is what it says

```
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
File - B7924596.5;sz=728x90;ord=1385842058148:57
```

I was getting the same error even in incognito mode.

On Firefox, it says that there's an error on file/line number - 20471.js (line 14)

Here's the question where I first saw the error

[How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Not sure if others are facing the same issue.

Comment: Looks like an issue cause by Flash (NPObject = browser plugin, most likely Flash) advert ("sz=728x90" = from ad.doubleclick.net)

Comment: @RobW I'm fairly certain that Stack Exchange does not allow animated or Flash advertisements. So if it's a Flash object then it certainly didn't come from here.

Comment: @animuson not directly, but it's using third party advertising sites. I just confirmed with low rep account and there is request to this JS file: https://ad-apac.doubleclick.net/adj/N5295.171779.STACKOVERFLOW.COM/B7939337.24;sz=728x90;ord=1385900196084? and it's spawning more JS files. The origin is most likely the top advertisement (above the question body) which is removed when reaching [200 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). (hence OP here didn't see it when logged in, having more than 200)

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome when I opened that link in an incognito window. It's related to a hidden Flash element being used in a Google Cloud Platform ad.

Comment: @animuson turns out it's not true anymore. [Proof of pure Flash ad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8YXjc.png).

Answer (score 8):

I can confirm I'm able to reproduce the error as well. Looking into the issue further now.

I'll post any relevant updates here.

---

Update:
It appears that the error was a result of secure content being served on the regular, http version of SO. The client provided non-SSL tags, which when tested, no longer created the NPObject error.

In anticipation of SO going fully secure, we've been requesting secure third-party tags from clients for a while now. Unfortunately in this instance, it backfired on us.

---

Update 2: Electric Boogaloo:
In case those concerned haven't noticed, the updated ads have been live for over a week now.

Comment: But this still only applies to Flash? (Just curious why, despite many refreshes, I did not get the error in my Chrome's Incognito mode. But my Flash setup has been modified to run very restricted, so that might explain things.)

Comment: @Arjan did you get to Google's Flash advertisement? Took me ~10 reloads to reach it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8YXjc.png (and the error kept repeating itself in endless loop)

Comment: stevvve so where does it stand now?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd waiting on updated creative from client; expect it to be here shortly, update reflected on SO shortly thereafter.

Comment: @stevvve we don't have ads here on Meta as far as I can tell, but looking forward to see it on SO.

Comment: Hmmm, @ShaWizDowArd, after refreshing like 100 times on a few different questions, I only got Careers (lots of them), Rackspace, Microsoft and Infragistics. But mostly Careers. Must be a hint... ;-)

Comment: @Arjan are you viewing question with a google tag? (I tested on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis) :))

Comment: @Arjan also, you have more than 200 rep so you must use Incognito/Private mode, we're talking about external ad here, displayed above the question not in the right sidebar.

Comment: @Arjan I encourage you *not* to do that, as it interferes with our methods of monitoring campaign performance. Also, the campaign in question has a frequency cap enabled, so if you've already seen it a certain number of times today you won't see it again. If you try incognito it should work, though.

Comment: I am just glad you guys were able to figure out the root cause. For a long time I thought it was just me facing the issue. This was my first bug report here. I feel awesome being able to help out at least that much!

Comment: Sure I was using incognito, @ShaWizDowArd. One of the tags I tested was Android, but maybe that was not Google enough. Just for your information, stevvve: I don't care but that was really a lot of Careers. For a long time I even thought it was *only* Careers.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for reporting, glad you had good first impression here. Many users get a cold shower on their first Meta participation so you're quite lucky. :-)