# Stack Overflow needz moar ads

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

[This got me thinking...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198627/proposed-contest-for-close-review-queue-posse)

Not about a contest though. I don't want people reviewing questions so that they'll *get* something in return; folks should be doing it because they care about the questions, about **their community**. If folks don't *care*, then what's the point?

But maybe folks *do* care, maybe they *do* see a problem... and they just don't realize that *they* can do anything about it!

There's a *really long tail* of questions in the queue right now. Questions in *crazy obscure topics* like "Matlab" and "Objective-C". Topics people *do* care about.

I'd like to eventually [build something into the UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface/209778#209778) that let the folks in these communities know that there's an opportunity for their voices to be heard regarding the fate of the questions they're working with.

But before we do that, let's see if folks *do* care.

Let's plaster the site with ads:

[image: Should 662 matlab questions be closed?]

We can target folks in specific topics, folks with enough reputation to review items in the close queue... And, now, [we can make the ads link directly *to* the close queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208287/allow-direct-linking-to-a-filtered-review-queue/209777#209777), filtered down to just the questions being targeted.

I'd like to start with maybe a dozen ads targeting medium-sized tags with maybe a few hundred pending review tasks associated with them.

What do you think?

Comment: Do it. Why have you waited 3 minutes from having the idea? Do it!

Comment: Sounds cool, but would directly linking to the tool not overwhelm people? Shouldn't there be an interstitial page (or Meta post) explaining what the whole thing is about?

Comment: I'm very discerning about the ads I want to see. The kittehs better be cute or funny, otherwise no halps!

Comment: Most folks reviewing right now don't find their way in from meta, @probablyPekka... If it's too confusing, then we probably need to fix that too. Note that for folks visiting a queue for the first time, the full instructions are expanded until they explicitly hide them.

Comment: I'm *very* open to suggestions, @slugster - as you can probably tell, I suck at designing ads.

Comment: Totally as an aside: while investigating [a bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209491/browser-console-repeatedly-prints-error-calling-method-on-npobject-on-stack-ov) I saw lots of Careers ads, and only a few others...

Comment: [cue uncle Sam] we want \*you\* to help us close some questions

Comment: What is missing in the particular example is a "why would I get involved here?". How can we make clear not only that we need help, but also what this help is exactly. Because one of the responses I could imagine with an add like that is "Oh hell no, you're not closing an X amount of posts in my favourite topic".

Comment: It is hard to write a catchy blurb that strikes the right balance between "662 crappy questions need to die in a fire" and "662 potentially helpful questions need to be rescued."

Comment: That poor Matlab kitty...

Comment: UX testing shows that there is an overwhelming tendancy for users to ignore ads or adlike things. (e.g. http://www.nngroup.com/articles/banner-blindness-old-and-new-findings/)

Comment: I [fixed that for you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/209779/revisions).    I love the idea, and I think the ad is already perfect.  Just make sure you're equal-opportunity and include puppies.

Comment: @TheGrinch your heart is two sizes too small to want to do that to the poor kitty.  Now, if it was the php kitty... oh dear.

Comment: @Shog9 Your ads need more pie charts!

Comment: @JanDvorak ["We need you" mockup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OgamS.jpg). Not sure how well it will be received by non-Americans, non-patriotic Americans or those who can't take a joke. Perhaps we can have one of the mods or SE team pose rather than just using the standard image. Anyway, just an idea.

Comment: "matlab" because that's (one of) the top tag(s) of whomever we are displaying it to, right?

Comment: Not quite, @Dukeling - it'd be a tag on the question (or questions list) that they're *viewing*. Don't think we can target ads according to viewer involvement.

Comment: @Dukeling eek you're right. We can't use uncle Sam here. Would something else in an uncle Sam pose (parodying uncle Sam) be plausible here?

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know about everyone else, but I find myself on plenty of questions containing tags I really couldn't care less about (often because a question containing tags I do care about simply contains those tag as well, other times because I just randomly find myself there).

Comment: This focus on "community" got me thinking (which is always dangerous). It seems the emphasis is always on "We're not (primarily) social". But in this case, a sense of community might certainly help. Is there something to be said to encourage more of a sense of community? Some tags seem to have it, but I don't see that across the site as whole. (Bart, that's a whole lot of words for not saying much at all)

Comment: I would totally be cool with having extra ads show up on my screen if they were both moderately humorous and SO-internal.

Comment: @Dukeling, for the UK, you can use [Lord Kitchener](https://www.google.com/search?q=kitchener) :)

Comment: Don't know about the specific idea here, but the underlying aim seems to be reducing the overwhelming size of the queue to manageable-seeming dimensions. For that alone, +1.

Comment: Is the deleted answer some kind of bizarre 10k+ easter egg?

Comment: Easter egg / scratch-pad for stuff I didn't want to type up again later. @Josh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550999/how-can-php-validate-strings-containing-gobbeldy-goop?noredirect=0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550999/how-can-php-validate-strings-containing-gobbeldy-goop?noredirect=0

Answer (score 24):

[Stevvve The Adnificent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178809/stevvve) has added the following six ads to the system:

[image: Delphi]
[image: Django]
[image: Matlab]
[image: NumPy]
[image: Vim]
[image: objective-c]

These *should* be showing up randomly to users with 5,000+ reputation who happen to be browsing through them.

We'll check back after a bit to see if it's made any difference...

Comment: Purely to satisfy my curiosity, could/would you report on their effect at some point?

Comment: Of course, @bart. Because your curiosity is my priority.

Comment: Need the kitten to be in more desperate situations to really attract people attention.

Comment: I'm not sure [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AIqlr.png) would get quite the right sort of attention, @Jonathan.

Comment: Why 5k reputation? Everyone with 3k can see the queues.

Comment: Because that's how the ad system is configured, @Cruncher. Rep thresholds are hard-coded at 5K+ and 10K+.

Comment: @Shog9 makes sense. I thought there was more control.

Comment: It's a cute thing and a good idea, however it could respect the filter you've configured for the close vote review queue, or at least apply the filter you set. Now it ignores anything you set there (I see, that tag filter should be "pre-filled" with the tag for which you've clicked the ad, but the close reason would be fine to filter out).

Comment: ...the whole point of the links is to point folks to specific tags in the queue, @TLama. They're *supposed* to override your saved filter. If you want to go back to your saved filter, just leave the queue and then re-enter via the normal route.

Comment: 2 months or 8 weeks (?) after, did they work?

Comment: They did, @braiam - could've sworn I wrote this up somewhere, but can't find it now

Answer (score 8):

As I pointed out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198627/proposed-contest-for-close-review-queue-posse/210737#210737), I love the idea of raising motivation for users to be involved in close review activities.

- I'm not very happy about the badge system because I suspect that kind of motivation creates the robo-reviewer behavior.
- I love the idea of "***Please Review Ads***", specifically targeted toward 3K+ rep users.
- Motivation is key. With over ***18,000*** *3K+* rep users on SO, if they were motivated to perform an average of 2 review tasks each per day, resulting in ***36,000*** close reviews per day, over ***1,000,000*** close reviews per month.

Comment: You're still asking 14 a week, and do to a proper close review can take a couple minutes. It's hard to ask for ~1hour/week work from 18000 people.

Comment: @Cruncher, I agree. But the scale of numbers is meant to show how much community cooperation is the issue and the potential of greater contributing.

Comment: @Cruncher There are many 'Me Help. Not Work' questions which you can review in 2 seconds. Unfortunatelly, there are very many of them.

Answer (score 4):

I would love to review questions. I only have 1.2K rep, though, and cannot. Ads would not help me be more involved in the process.

I understand that the point of the ads would be to remind users who can review to do so. If you show these ads, please be sure not to show them to users who can't participate!

Comment: This is already clearly covered in the post: *We can target folks in specific topics, folks **with enough reputation** to review items in the close queue*

Comment: So it does. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I think Kevin was hinting that lowering the 3K barrier would be another way to help.

Comment: @DaveA not sure, see last sentence.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I did see that. I'm reading into this a little (considering the nature of his answer). I could be way off.

Comment: I thought of that while I was writing the answer. I know that others have floated the idea already, so I decided to focus on asking Shog9 not to try to get users excited to close votes if they can't.