# Don't show me the new "come review" ads after I've hit the daily limit

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, advertising

As I'm sure many of you know, SE recently [introduced some ads to encourage users to pitch in on the 101k+ and growing close queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209779/172958).

Today I finally saw one of them.  That's fine, I really haven't been doing as many reviews as I should anyway.  Except today I did max out the daily review queue quota.  And I'm only now seeing ads.  But I can't do any more for that queue, so the ad is entirely useless.

So, please don't show the review queue ads to those of us who have already hit the daily max, there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 4):

Can't do that, I'm afraid.

This is just temporary anyway, a test to see if a bit of evangelism can bring in some new blood. Ads happen to be the *only* system available for targeting users in specific tags at specific rep-levels, so... Ads it is. But even the advertising system isn't flexible enough to target folks based on the number of reviews they've done (or haven't done) on a given day.

Definitely something worth keeping in mind for any future [purpose-built review notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar) though.